# How to use actual text instead of placeholder text?

Tags: html, forms, input, field

When working with input fields, is it possible to use actual text in the input fields instead of the transparent placeholder text.

With the contact form I am working on, I want to have pre-entered text, so the user just has to click submit.

Comment: So do not use placeholder? Use value?

Answer (score 1):

Use the value attribute `<input type="text" value="default">`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you can use the `value` attribute.

For input fields you can use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="Peter">
```

For `select` elements you can use it like this:

```
<select id=“laptops” name="laptops">
  <option value="dell">Dell</option>
  <option value="lenovo">Lenovo</option>
  <option value="acer">Acer</option>
  <option value="hp">HP</option>
</select>
```

For `textarea` you cannot add a value attribute. The best way to add default value is to add it between the tags like this:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="5">
    default value
</textarea>
```